# Encrypted LVM on RAID1 - Failure testing, manual mount

Tags: ubuntu, raid, encryption, software-raid

We have an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server set up with LVM running on top of disk encryption, which runs on top of a RAID1 volume comprised of two physical SATA disks.  The configuration looks like this:

```
             _______________
            |swap|     /    | - LVM volume for swap (10 GB)
            |____|__________| - LVM volume for root (rem. space ~ 490 GB)
            |______LVG0_____|  - LVM group  
           /d0fc97a3b3e8ae5a8\    - dm-crypt encrypted partition on RAID1
    ______/___________________\______
   |/boot|  > RAID1 | > RAID1  |/boot| - 250MB /boot partition on each disk
   |_____|__________|__________|_____| - remaining space on each for RAID
   |______500 GB____|____500 GB______|   - SATA HDD x 2
```

This works just great, however when I go to simulate a cold disk failure (shutdown, unplug one or the other of the disks, and power up), it fails to prompt for my boot passphrase and shows the error:

`cryptsetup: LVM device name (dev/disk/by-UUID/[UUID String]) does not begin with /dev/mapper`

After about a 5 minute wait, it will come up with a BusyBox `(initramfs)` prompt.  My question is, why won't it ask for the boot passphrase when booted this way from either disk?  I did choose the option to continue booting after a disk failure when I installed the RAID partition, but this obviously isn't happening.  Second, how can I manually get it to unlock the remaining disk from the RAID array and boot properly using the BusyBox shell?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** As requested, here's the output of pvdisplay run after it boots with both drive plugged in:

```
   --- Physical volume ---
   PV Name               /dev/mapper/[md disk]_crypt
   VG Name               [LVM group name]
   PV Size               465.53 GiB / not usable 2.93 MiB
   Allocatable           yes (but full)
   PE Size               4.00 MiB
   Total PE              119174
   Free PE               0
   Allocated PE          119174
   PV UUID               [UUID]
```

When only one drive is plugged in, it eventually drops me to a BusyBox shell where pvdisplay is not available.

**UPDATE:** 
I came across [this debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=554506) from the end of last year that matched my problem pretty well.  It appears to have been fixed, so I manually installed the updated cryptsetup, libcryptsetup1, and libpop0 packages from upstream.

Now when I boot with either disk unplugged, I don't get the error anymore, and it asks for a passphrase properly.  However, it *won't accept the password I've configured.*  With both disks plugged in, it accepts the password and boots as normal, but with either one unplugged it gets to asking for the passphrase won't accept the correct password.

**UPDATE 2:**
The symptoms now appear identical to the [bug report filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/324997) here, though I'm running Lucid.  As described in the link, I can get it to boot from a single disk -- if I generate enough failures it will eventually kick me out to the BusyBox shell again, and I can run `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md1 md1_crypt`, enter the password, and then hit `ctrl-d` to get it to boot.  This seems like a bizarre procedure to get it to boot in a degraded state.  I think I'm going to wipe everything and start over.  Since I haven't run into this before I'm hoping a fresh install may fix things, and if not I at least know how to boot the degraded array if I need to.

Comment: Does passing `bootdegraded=true` as a kernel boot option fix it?

Comment: My understanding is that this is exactly what the mdadm option that I mentioned above does, but I'll check grub for this tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: What does `pvdisplay` say after a normal boot vs a single-drive boot?

Comment: See Edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should believe the error that says that the device `does not begin with /dev/mapper`. I have `cryptsetup` here and it works fine, but all my devices are named `/dev/mapper/something`.

I know you want to use the UUID to mount it, but apparently that is not supported right out of the box.

Comment: Take the error at face value?!  Inconceivable! ;-)   So, it's loading the RAID partition as /dev/mapper/* when it finds both of the mirrored disks, but since the individual devices aren't in /dev/mapper, it won't boot either individually?  Hadn't considered that, thanks.

Comment: How is your `/etc/crypttab`? This one points to `/dev/mapper` too, but on other computer I have a `/etc/crypttab` uses UUIDS, but on this one I use dm-raid and on the other its plain disks, so I guess its a requirement from raid devices.

Comment: Thanks, @coredump, it was by 'UUID=' so I switched it and rebooted.  However, again when I cold-unplug one disk and boot, I get the same cryptsetup error as above with the 'disk/by-UUID/' path.  Where does cryptsetup get its device info from if it isn't using crypttab?

Comment: See update above.

Comment: This got me on the right track to direct my google-fu, so I'm marking as answer. Thanks for your help!