# Software RAID, LVM, and Encryption Setup Questions

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, encryption, software-raid, raid10

I have 4 hard drives, each with two partitions on them `10.1GB` for swap and `990.1GB` for the rest.

I took this and set up two MD devices with RAID10, one for the set of 4 swap partitions and one for the set of 4 other partitions.

I set the `20.2GB` Software RAID device as my swap and moved on to LVM.

This is as far as [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/serverguide.pdf) takes me using software RAID. I would now like to set up LVM and encryption on it.

I created a new volume and logical volume; size `1.5TB`. I encrypted the volume and set the remaining `1.4TB` within the encrypted volume as the root (`f ext4 /`).

Here are my questions:

Should I set up a separate Volume / Logical Volume for the `20.2GB` Software RAID device being used as a swap area?

Should I encrypt this volume as well if I'm encrypting the `ext4 /` area?

`Finish partitioning and write changes to disk` gives an error of:

> You have selected the root file system
>   to be stored on an encrypted
>   partition. This feature requires a
>   separate /boot partition on which the
>   kernel and initrd can be stored.
>
> you should go back and setup a /boot
>   partition.

Where does this `/boot` partition need to be setup? (Should each drive have an extra partition for this before setting up RAID?)

How much space does it need?

Should it be part of LVM?

Should it be encrypted?

Comment: [Here's how we set up encryption + RAID + LVM.](http://serverfault.com/questions/261104/encrypted-lvm-on-raid1-failure-testing-manual-mount)  2 partitions on each disk for RAID: 1@250MB, 1@remaining space. Create the RAID arrays and place `/boot` on the 250MB one; the other RAID vol gets an encrypted volume on the whole thing.  Create an LVM group in the encrypted volume, and 2 LVM volumes: 1@10GB assigned to `swap`, and 1 with the remaining space assigned to `/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/boot` needs to not be encrypted otherwise the boot loader (unless I'm behind the times and one of them supports encrypted volumes) will not be able to ready the Kernel and initrd. It does not need to be encrypted as it should never contain anything other than the kernel, the initrd, and perhaps a few other support files.

The the device that is your LVM PV is encrypted, then `/boot` will need to be elsewhere: probably a separate RAID volume. If the device used as the PV is not encrypted (instead you encrypted the LV that is to be `/`) then `/boot` could be in the LVM except for the GRUB-can't-boot-off-all-RAID-types issue (see below).

Historically `/boot` had to be near the start of the disk, but modern boot loaders generally remove this requirement. A few hundred Mb should be perfectly sufficient, but with such large drives being standard these days there will be no harm in making it bigger just in case unless you are constrained by trying to fit into a very small device (say, a small SD card in a Pi or similar) as might be the case for an embedded system.

Most boot loaders do not support booting off RAID or if they do they only support booting off RAID1 (where every drive has a copy all the data) "by accident", so create the small partition on all the drives and use a RAID1 array over them. This way `/boot` is readable as long as at least one drive is in a working state. Make sure the boot loaded installs into the MBR of all four drives on install, otherwise if you BIOS boots off another (due to the first being offline for instance) you will have to mess around getting the loader's MBR onto the other drive(s) at that point rather than it already being there.

**Update:** As per Nick's comment below, modern boot loaders can deal directly with some forms of encrypted volumes so depending on your target setup there are now less things to worry about.

Comment: So the "/boot" would be set as bootable instead of the "/"?

Comment: Also, should the swap area be in a different Physical Volume or Logical Volume? Or should it be in the same as the root "/"; should it be encrypted as well?

Comment: It is often recommended that swap be encrypted in situations where you care enough about the data to encrypt it, as it will be held in memory in plain form so may get swapped out to disk in that form when memory is low. It can be in the same PV as `/`. Yes, `/boot` should be the bootable partition on each drive, though IIRC with a modern bootloader in the MBR this makes little difference.

Comment: Note that GRUB2 now (circa 2015) supports booting kernels from LUKS encrypted /boot partitions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't set up software RAID-10 using the installer, but I think some of the things I ran into while setting up Debian with RAID-1 + LVM + encryption might help.  I don't know how Debian's console installer differs from Ubuntu's installer, so I can't offer details on how to do this.

For `/boot`, GRUB2 has `raid` and `lvm` modules that can be loaded with its `insmod` command [which should handle Linux's md raid10 layout](http://www.mail-archive.com/grub-devel@gnu.org/msg08345.html).  The exact details are apparently [here](http://grub.enbug.org/LVMandRAID) but the site is down.  Based on the information I'm getting from their manual ([you may have somewhere from 31KiB to 1MiB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#BIOS-installation), my `core.img` is 24KB already, and `raid.mod` and `lvm.mod` are 6KB each) so you may or may not be able to use it depending on how much space your partitioning tool wastes.  Even if it did fit, you may not be able to get Ubuntu's installer to set it up for you.  Unless you feel like risking more time on it, I'd stick to David's separate partition using RAID-1 (which won't need any extra modules since it "accidentally" works as long as you install grub to all of the drives' MBRs individually).  Either way, it can't be encrypted.

As for data and swap, if you are planning to RAID-10 both of them and enter them into LVM and encrypt them, then there isn't a point to making them separate partitions.  Make one giant partition on each drive and handle the division in LVM.

So if you aren't going to try the grub2 lvm+raid modules, your partitions should look something like:

- sd[abcd]1: 100MB
- sd[abcd]2: everything else

with

- sd[abcd]1 configured as RAID 1
- sd[abcd]2 configured as RAID 10

At this point, you create a LVM group using the larger RAID device as its physical volume, and then whatever logical volumes you'd like.

If you really want whole disk encryption then I would set up `/tmp` as a logical volume with a random key, and then `/` being an encrypted logical volume covering the rest of the space.  Keeping `/tmp` as a separate partition at least keeps people from filling up the filesystem with temp files and causing logging and other things to break.

Otherwise, take stock of what you want to encrypt.  Decide whether you want to have separate encrypted logical volumes so that you can have some encrypted data (eg data backup) not mounted all the time.  If having specific programs installed is not what you're hiding, then consider having a specific location (`/home`) encrypted while `/` is unencrypted.  Of course, you may have more than one location that needs to be encrypted but not want to enter a half dozen passphrases to boot.

Personally, what I do is create a (*totally* not FHS compliant) `/crypt` filesystem, and symlink every directory I want to protect into there. (note: this technique makes it obvious that you have encrypted data and possibly *what* data it is.  Naming your symlink Project_Orion_Nuclear_Spacedrive is probably leaking more information than you'd like.) Planned correctly, the system can even boot unattended and someone can enter the passphrase later.  For instance, my database servers and their encrypted drives are set to not automatically mount or run at boot, so the system will boot up enough for me to ssh in, then I can mount the filesystem and start the database server after a reboot.