# Problem with setting up partitions - encrypted swap partition won't mount

Tags: ubuntu, partition, lvm, encryption, swap

Here's the layout I have; I'm using Software RAID10, LVM, and Encryption:

```
LVM VG vg0, LV main - 2.0 TB Linux device-mapper (linear)
    #1              2.0 TB    K    crypto       (vg0-main_crypt)
Encrypted volume (vg0-main_crypt) - 2.0TB Linux device-mapper (linear)
                   61.4 kB         unusable
    #1              2.0 TB    f    ext4         /
LVM VG vg0, LV swap - 10.1GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
    #1             10.1 GB    K    crypto       (vg0-swap_crypt)
Encrypted volume (vg0-swap_crypt) - 2.0TB Linux device-mapper (linear)
                   61.4 kB         unusable
    #1             10.1 GB    f    swap         swap
                   65.5 kB         unusable
RAID10 device #0 - 20.2 GB Software RAID device
    #1             20.2 GB    K    lvm
                  131.1 kB         unusable
RAID10 device #1 - 2.0 TB Software RAID device
    #1              2.0 TB    K    lvm
                  131.1 kB         unusable
RAID1 device #2 - 298.8 MB Unknown
    #1            298.8 MB    K    ext4         /boot     
SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sdb) - 16.0 GB Verbatim STORE N GO
    #1   primary   16.0 GB  B      fat32
SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sdb) - 1.0 TB ATA WDC WD1002FAEX-0
    #1   primary  298.8 MB  B K    raid
    #1   primary   10.1 GB    K    raid
    #1   primary  989.8 GB    K    raid
SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sdc) - 1.0 TB ATA WDC WD1002FAEX-0
    #1   primary  298.8 MB  B K    raid
    #1   primary   10.1 GB    K    raid
    #1   primary  989.8 GB    K    raid
SCSI4 (0,0,0) (sdd) - 1.0 TB ATA WDC WD1002FAEX-0
    #1   primary  298.8 MB  B K    raid
    #1   primary   10.1 GB    K    raid
    #1   primary  989.8 GB    K    raid
SCSI5 (0,0,0) (sde) - 1.0 TB ATA WDC WD1001FALS-7
    #1   primary  298.8 MB  B K    raid
    #1   primary   10.1 GB    K    raid
    #1   primary  989.8 GB    K    raid
```

The error I'm getting now is:

> The attempt to mount a file system
>   with type swap in Encrypted volume
>   (vg0-swap_crypt) at none failed.

What am I doing wrong? When I had the swap unencrypted it said that I should encrypt it because it's unsafe not to (if I'm encrypting the rest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rearranging to only have 2 RAID partitions -- 1 for `/boot` and 1 for the rest of the space; the partition with the remaining space gets a single encrypted volume.  The encrypted volume has an LVM group on top of it with 2 LVM volumes, `swap` and `/`

[See my previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/261104/encrypted-lvm-on-raid1-failure-testing-manual-mount) for a little more detail.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I wish I could upvote you more...