# Implementing Linux fstrim on SSD with software md-raid

Tags: linux, software-raid, ssd

I'm currently building a new Ubuntu 13.04 server with 2 256GB SSDs in a raid mirror to run a MariaDB instance.  We typically place [LVM on top of dm-crypt encryption on top of an md raid 1 array](https://serverfault.com/questions/261104/encrypted-lvm-on-raid1-failure-testing-manual-mount), but haven't used SSDs in this setup previously.

My question is, since we'll be using a newer (3.8) kernel, it *should* allow fstrim to be applied to the raid volume directly as I understand it.  Can I now simply rely on this to work properly with `fstrim -v /` via a cron job, just as I would if the raid wasn't in place?  Is this true even with LVM on top of the raid volume?  We plan to use the hardware encryption present on the drives, so we won't need dm-crypt here.

**NOTE:** I'm aware that there are several similar questions involving backporting updated kernel versions and implementing discard with the md volume -- I'm asking specifically if `fstrim` works against md-raid without further modification in newer kernels.

**UPDATE:** Just wanted to follow up and post that this worked fine.  There's now a job in cron.daily that runs fstrim on `/` and `/boot` and it's working perfectly.  Also, it turned out the hardware encryption on the SSDs (Samsung 840 Pros) appears to require TPM support, which we don't have, so we did configure with software encryption as shown in the link. By adding `discard` to the options in `/etc/crypttab` (**not** to `/etc/fstab`) and `issue_discards = 1` to the devices section of `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`, fstrim works fine even through LVM, encryption, and RAID layers.  [More info about configuring for trim/discard on SSDs with LVM and encryption is available here.](http://blog.neutrino.es/2013/howto-properly-activate-trim-for-your-ssd-on-linux-fstrim-lvm-and-dmcrypt/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Patches for mdraid RAID 1 and 10 support for TRIM went up about a year ago.

You can test your kernel's support by mounting the filesystem with the `discard` option (which enables automatic TRIM). If it is supported, you'll see a message in syslog or `dmesg` like the following:

```
EXT4-fs (md1): re-mounted. Opts: discard,data=ordered
```

Otherwise you would get this:

```
EXT4-fs warning (device md1): ext4_issue_discard:2619: discard not supported, disabling
```

You don't need to reboot to see if it's working:

```
mount /dir -o remount
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, if mounting with discard works, then fstrim should as well?

Comment: Correct. If it's fully implemented all the way down, then it will work either way.

Comment: Remember to change the mount options afterward, if you don't intend to do automatic TRIM. :)

Comment: For the record, TRIM support for RAID1 was added on October 11 2012, see here http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1203.1/01772.html
So kernel 3.4 doesn't support it but 3.8 does (don't know about 3.5/3.6/3.7)

Comment: Any idea if this is backported in precise or trusty? Is the only way to find out to try it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton that is unfortunately not true. For example, having kernel 3.2, with ext4 on LVM on MD(soft) RAID1, (re)mounting ext4 with discard won't report error, but won't work either (as MD RAID1 in 3.2.x kernels don't support passing down of TRIM commands). So only way to know for sure is to [test it](https://clusterbuffer.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/how-do-you-know-trim-is-working-with-your-ssd-in-your-system/)